# ¿Cómo pintar una celda en Delphi con Dev-express tendiendo en cuenta dos criterios de celda?

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-2010

Con el siguiente código puedo pintar de forma exitosa una celda siguiendo un criterio

```
procedure TfMain.gridDBColumnGrid1DBTableView1FECHAINICOStylesGetContentStyle(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; out AStyle: TcxStyle);
var
  AColumnFechaInicio, AColumnFechaFin: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
begin
  AColumnFechaInicio := (Sender as TcxGridDBTableView).GetColumnByFieldName('FECHAINICO');
  // AColumnFechaFin := (Sender as TcxGridDBTableView).GetColumnByFieldName('FECHAFIN');
  //if Hoy >= IncMinute(ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaInicio.Index], -30) and Hoy >= ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaFin.Index] then
  if Hoy >= IncMinute(ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaInicio.Index], -30) then
  begin
    AStyle := cxStyleGreen;
  end;
end;
```

Ahora quiero pintar la misma celda utilizando dos criterios, pero me muestra error

```
procedure TfMain.gridDBColumnGrid1DBTableView1FECHAINICOStylesGetContentStyle(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; out AStyle: TcxStyle);
var
  AColumnFechaInicio, AColumnFechaFin: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
begin
  AColumnFechaInicio := (Sender as TcxGridDBTableView).GetColumnByFieldName('FECHAINICO');
   AColumnFechaFin := (Sender as TcxGridDBTableView).GetColumnByFieldName('FECHAFIN');
  if Hoy >= IncMinute(ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaInicio.Index], -30) and Hoy >= ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaFin.Index] then
  //if Hoy >= IncMinute(ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaInicio.Index], -30) then
  begin
    AStyle := cxStyleGreen;
  end;
end;
```

Error de compilación

> [DCC Error] uMain.pas(127): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

¿Cómo hacer para obtener el valor de otra celda de la misma fila?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error en IF, debe estar entre paréntesis

```
IF (CONDICIÓN 1) AND (CONDICIÓN 2) then
begin
  Instrucción
end;
```

Esto se debe a que en pascal:

- los operadores `and` y `or`, además de operadores lógicos, son operadores binarios.
- el operadores operadores `and` tienen [mayor precedencia](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence) que los operadores de comparación, como `>`, `<`, `>=`, etc.

Por estas razones, al no encerrar tus condiciones entre paréntesis, lo que el compilador *entiende* que quieres hacer es:

```
if Hoy >= (IncMinute(ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaInicio.Index], -30) and Hoy) >= ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaFin.Index] then
```

En la expresión anterior, he añadido paréntesis para tratar de aclararlo. Es decir, primero intenta realizar la operación binaria:

```
IncMinute(ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaInicio.Index], -30) and Hoy
```

Por suerte, la operación `and` no está definida para tipos de dato TDateTime (que son en realidad números de coma flotante), que es lo que dice el mensaje de error (que de otra forma parecería no tener sentido).

Dicho esto, la solución a tu problema sería esta:

```
procedure TfMain.gridDBColumnGrid1DBTableView1FECHAINICOStylesGetContentStyle(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord; AItem: TcxCustomGridTableItem; out AStyle: TcxStyle);
var
  AColumnFechaInicio, AColumnFechaFin: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
begin
  AColumnFechaInicio := (Sender as TcxGridDBTableView).GetColumnByFieldName('FECHAINICO');
   AColumnFechaFin := (Sender as TcxGridDBTableView).GetColumnByFieldName('FECHAFIN');
  if (Hoy >= IncMinute(ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaInicio.Index], -30)) and (Hoy >= ARecord.Values[AColumnFechaFin.Index]) then

  begin
    AStyle := cxStyleGreen;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, ahora todo queda más claro ya que agregas el porqué de las cosas... el pesos de los operadores y la razón del mensaje del compilador.

Comment: Un gusto contribuir.